# Vb.net - Transferring balance to another "User" is not updating on my database using MSAcess

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm a noob in database, and I am making an ATM System using vb.net and MS Access. There is a button named "Fund Transfer". When I click the button, it should decrease the balance of User A and increase the balance of User B.

However, when I click the button, it says "Amount Transfered" but the balance of both User was not updated on database.

This is my code:

```
    Dim i, currentrow As Integer
    Dim maxrows As Integer
    i = 0

    While i <> maxrows + 1
        If lblAccno.Text = ds.Tables("G1 FINALS LOGIN CREATE").Rows(i)("ACCNO") Then
            current = ds.Tables("G1 FINALS LOGIN CREATE").Rows(i)("BALANCE")
            balance = current - txtSendAmount.Text

            Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            ds.Tables("G1 FINALS LOGIN CREATE").Rows(i).Item("BALANCE") = balance
            da.Update(ds, "G1 FINALS LOGIN CREATE")

        End If

        If txtboxRecAccno.Text = ds.Tables("G1 FINALS LOGIN CREATE").Rows(i)("ACCNO") Then
            current = ds.Tables("G1 FINALS LOGIN CREATE").Rows(i)("BALANCE")
            balance = current + txtSendAmount.Text

            Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            ds.Tables("G1 FINALS LOGIN CREATE").Rows(i).Item("BALANCE") = balance
            da.Update(ds, "G1 FINALS LOGIN CREATE")
            Exit While
        End If

        i += 1

    End While
    MsgBox("Amount Transfered!")
    Me.Close()
    Dashboard.Show()
    currentrow = i
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Balances should not be saved but calculated from transaction records.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code (F8) and verified that all code gets executed as you envisioned it?

Comment: Yes, the codes are running without errors. The problem is that the balance is not updating in the database.

Comment: What happens if you try running the same query manually in Access?

Comment: Could you update your question with the contents of the da.UpdateCommand property?